# 'Unable to import' error message in Q# using VS Code

Tags: programming, q#

I'm a complete beginner in Q#.

Consider the code in the following image:

[image]

For some reason, there always is an error message when I try to import anything. It also implies to keywords like `Length`. The error message is :

```
No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.Canon" exists.
```

However, my code works just fine. The code in the image is taken directly from user guide of Q#.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code builds and runs successfully, this error has to come from IntelliSense.

Are you using .NET Core 3.1.300? I think QDK release 0.11.2004.2825 has IntelliSense issues with .NET Core 3.1.300 specifically, and downgrading .NET Core to 3.1.201 fixes this issue - you can try that.

Edit: the [relevant issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler/issues/434).

Comment: I'm the person that asked the same question on Gitter few hours ago when Stack Exchange didn't provide any answer, thank you for the second time lol.